# Grouping with certain numbers belonging to a parent number

Tags: sql

I have a rather simple query

```
Select count(*) from tableTest 
    Where s_date >= current_date
    Group by employee
```

And this works, but I'm trying to export these records so that certain employees are grouped into one number

So say I had records like this

```
Employee | count
- - - - - - - - -
123         2
321         3
625         4
827         5
216         3
```

But let's say employee 123's records count for their own but all other employees numbers belong to employee 321

How can I change that to get my result set to be

```
Employee | count
- - - - - - - - -
123         2
321         15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when employee = 123 then 123 else 321 end),
       count(*)
from tableTest 
where s_date >= current_date
group by (case when employee = 123 then 123 else 321 end);
```

Comment: Thanks! That should be what I need. If need be, can I have multiple options in the case? If I wanted to do this for multiple numbers

Comment: @Whisou138 . . . Yes, just add more `when` clauses.